# silverlight xaml staticresouce performance

Tags: silverlight, xaml, staticresource

Is there a notable performance difference in really large applications between the following two definitions?

```
<Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource Segoe}" />

<Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe OI" />
```

I have the same question for colors/brushes and other types. Are static resources notably slower?

Comment: I'm just curious what benefit you would get from chaining resources like your first example in the first place? In my experience, the more places/times anything has to jump around resources to find what it needs then the more impact you'll see from those additional steps.

Comment: Its not about chaining. It would be a direct lookup for perhaps the textbox border color to a centrally defined brush.
Its just that there could be hundreds of textboxes later in a view. Of course the assumption is that it is slower. But HOW MUCH slower? Is worth going through some pain during the development phase because of it?

Answer (score 0):

Before thinking about performance issues like this, think of use case of StaticResources. In larege program you cannot set styles in your every line of code. Any future change can be painful. You need to centralized your styles.

Think of it in way that you need it. Don't waste your time on such worthless performance consideration.